# Min-Width Media Query Achieving Undesired Results

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

How do I achieve the perfect balance of min-width and max-width to get my web page mobile-responsive first? I got no response to my previous question, and I've been struggling to find a solution all weekend :(. I'm trying to get my web page to have **each div** in **each grid row** to occupy **one column only** from **`500px` to `0px`** and to maintain its **regular non-`@media query`** character from **`500px` upward**.

Here is the link to my Code Pen:https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/Xevyqq

Here is my html code:

```
<html>
  <title></title>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="Main">
        <div class="Header Box">
          <div id="One"> 
            <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/2gy4am3oov/Satellite_over_earth_2.jpg" width="200px" height="126px"/>
          </div>
          <div id="Two"><p>ETHERSONIC</p><p>TECHNOLOGIES</p>     
          </div>
          <div id="Three"> blah blah blah blah blah
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "Second Row">
          <div class="About Us">
          Technology you can trust

  <p>Ethersonic Technologies has been servicing Chicago and the surrounding suburbs since April 2008. We are a Certified (VOSB) Veteran Owned Small Business with the Federal Government and a member of the BB​B (Better Business Bureau) with an A+ rating.</p>

  <p>Ethersonic specializes in Computer  diagnosis and repair, Security Camera Installation and repair and Network Installation and Repair</p>
        </div>
        <div class="BBB VOSB">
          <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/284vrnvfsv/BBB_and_VOSB_Logos.jpg" width="200" height="124"/>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="Third Row">
          <div id="Computers">
        <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/1dv3jss5yn/asus-reveals-the-rog-g11-gaming-desktop-491165-2.jpg" width="300" height="203"/>
            <p>
              Desktop and Laptop Repair
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="Security">
          <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/8j0ejlsp7j/Security_Cameras.jpg
" width="300" height="201"/>
            <p>
             Security Camera Systems | <br>
Access Controls Systems |
Intercom Systems 
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="Networking">
          <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/6gklvjubvz/switches.png" width="300" height="300"/>
            <p>
             Network Installation |
Low Voltage Cabling 
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Fourth Row">
        <div id="slider">
      <figure>
 <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/7uayt1hjf3/378c87079dddbfe1d78c9f892695626fl-m0xd-w1020_h770_q80.jpg"/>
<img src="https://s1.postimg.org/11px6krrfz/extralarge.jpg"/>
<img src="https://s1.postimg.org/6yehdl959r/gen_Mid.09186160_1.jpg"/>
<img src="https://s1.postimg.org/8tr267l5fz/ISaly9e2xn0r8r1000000000.jpg"/>
<img src="https://s1.postimg.org/11px6krz5r/ISinl3p5sts48e1000000000_1.jpg"/>
</figure>        
      </div> 
      <div class ="Slideshow Description">
        <p>
          We are Installation Experts! <br>
Offering Customized Installation for Both Residentials and Commercial Properties
        </p>
      </div>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my current CSS code:

```
   body{
      margin: 5px 125px 0 125px;
    }

    .Main{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1/1r;
      /*background-color: green;*/
    } 

    div.Main{
      /*box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      border: 0.125em solid black;
      overflow: hidden;*/
    }


    .Header.Box {
      display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      /*background-color: red;*/
      grid-gap: 0;
    }

    .About.Us{
      font-size: 15px
    }

    .BBB.VOSB{
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }

    #One, #Two, #Three {
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;  
    }

    .Second.Row{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }

    .Third.Row{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 25px;
      /*background-color: green;*/
    }

    #Computers, #Security, #Networking{
       /*border-style: solid;*/
        border-color: black;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;

    }


    .Fourth.Row{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 25px;
      /*background-color: blue;*/
    }


    @keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
    }


    div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
    div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
    div#slider figure { 
      position: relative;
      width: 500%;
      margin: 0;
      left: 0;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 0;
      animation: 10s slidy infinite; 
    }

    .Slideshow.Description{
      font-size: 1.25em;
    }


     @media (min-width: 500px){
    .Header.Row{ 
      display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
        } 
    }

    /* Second Row*/
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
    .Second.Row{
      display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      }

    }

      @media (max-width: 500px) {
    .About.Us{
      font-size: 10px !important;
    }

     @media (min-width: 320px) {
    .About.Us{
      font-size: 12px;
    }


    @media (min-width: 500px) {
    .BBB.VOSB img{
      width: 200px;
      height: 124px;
      display: grid;
      }  
    }  

    /*Third Row*/



     @media (max-width: 500px) {
    .Third.Row{
      display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      }

    }


    @media (min-width: 320px) {
    .Fourth.Row{
      display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      }
    }
```

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to get the web page to have **each div** in **each grid row** occupy **one column only** from **`500px` to `0px`** while maintaining its **regular non-`@media query`** character from **`500px` upward**.. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Huangism, my goal is to not use max-width, at least not preliminary, because I want the website to be mobile-responsive first.

Comment: @Huangism...that's what I originally did...wrote the CSS then used min-width in the media-queries to enable it to be mobile-responsive first...but they only work to precisely 500px. Below 500px and beyond 500px the code resumes normal pre-media query character. I tried to combine max-width media-queries with it but it wouldn't work....hence the point of this topic-question... Just using max-width is easy...I know how to do that...I want to use min-width first and then tweak it with max-width.....and there I'm getting stuck!

Comment: @Huangism .....its in the code...example: 

media (min-width: 500px){
        .Header.Row{ 
          display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
            } 
        }

Comment: @Huangism, I just reduced it. Thanks for having patience with me! I'm really trying to jump into the the new CSS Grid technology and do amazing things with it so I can become an expert. Cheers!

Comment: I never actually used css grid yet but it shouldn't be that hard to figure out. Can you tell me what part of your code works right now? The styles above 500 or under?

Comment: The part of the code that works right now is that the requirements for the min-width media query works exactly at 500px, but below 500px and over 500px, the webpage reverts back to its original behavior....see link here:https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/Xevyqq

Comment: Ok I see the Pen, I also see max width and min width media queries, as far as I understand it you want something above 500(400 in pen) and something under it. SO I don't understand why you would have min and max, you would just need one of them, the rest can just be normal styles for either above or under 500. Tell me what you are trying to achieve above 500 and under 500 for ONE section and we will go from there

Comment: Hi @Huangism, the 400px has now been changed to 500px. And the "max-width" was an accident, it was a leftover from trying something previously. Now one example of what I want to achieve is for the first row, ('class="Header Box"'), to have each of its divs (About Us and BBB VOSB) stacked vertically at 500px and below, but remain normally horizontally placed  at above 500px. Thanks once again for your help!

Comment: Check https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaPYxV I changed the 500 to 800 so it is easier to see the change. I also removed some other stuff and only focusing on the header. Check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ for more grid info, it's a good site with good visuals for learning.

Comment: @Huangism, you created exactly what I wanted for the first row....but how could it be done with min-width instead of max-width alone? Because I want it to be mobile-first and then scale to desktop size rather than desktop first and then scale to mobile...also....another problem I have is the slideshow in the fourth row scales down into oblivion when I shrink the screen size and scales up huge when I enlarge the screen size...I don't know why it does that?

Comment: I think you need learn how grid works from that link I give you, I can't teach you everything on here. You need to read and understand it. Having max-width or min-width does not determine mobile first or not. If you want to use min-width then just take the stuff out of the current max width and swap it with the styles not in media query then change max-width to min-width https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPGREe the only change i made is in .Header.Box